# Cloud based fog of war

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph, fog-of-war, unity-urp, clouds

I'm working on a Unity 3D game that requires fog of war. It is seen from above. I was looking for help and found this: (I dont know what game it is though)

[image]

This would perfectly fit my needs but I don't know how to do it.
I created a grid of flat hexagons and tried applying shaders but the results are not satisfying. If we look at the image, we can see that the clouds are made of hexagons tiles too and the texture blend with the neighbouring tiles without seams.

My needs are:

- Clouds can be tiled so that I can remove them as the player explore the world
- Texture blends with it's neighbours
- Texture tiling is non-existant or not obvious
- Animated
- Opaque (I don't want the player to be able to see through it)

I'm literally trying to do the exact same thing as the GIF. For info, I'm using URP.

Any help or clues would be very appreciated.

**EDIT:** see Mangata comment for the solution

Comment: Hello, The game in the picture is [Sid Meier's Civilization V](https://store.steampowered.com/app/8930/Sid_Meiers_Civilization_V/). For your question, Have you searched extensively for information already available on the internet like [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/829748/how-to-make-a-fog-of-war-on-tile-based-map.html) or [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30013/how-do-i-implement-fog-of-war-in-a-tile-based-game)? Hope it helps.

Comment: It is Civ? I thought it wasnt. The 1st link you sent looks interesting, but the thing i'm looking isnt how to make it work, it is how to make it look good. I've been looking online for a couple days now, trying stuff out but nothing looks as i want. I need a tutorial or asset to get the results in the GIF.

Comment: oh, It's [Warlock](https://store.steampowered.com/app/203630/Warlock__Master_of_the_Arcane/). They look so similar :D . As for the cloud simulation, The clouds in the picture are occluding each other, so it's probably is simulated by mesh. Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7r5n5TsX_E)

Comment: Oh my lord, Thank you Mangata. The tutorial took a while to complete since he is speaking fast but I am so pleased with the results.

Comment: Please post an Answer detailing your solution. Solutions in comments don't count for the way the StackExchange system works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Mangata](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/161431/mangata) for finding [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7r5n5TsX_E&ab_channel=RomanPapush) tutorial. It was exactly what I was looking for.

Using a small hexagonal tile I made in blender, I followed the tutorial to create the shader in ShaderGraph. In game, when a unit explores the world, I shrink (and then remove it entirely) the tile above it. Works like a charm.

Comment: You can accept your own answer after a short delay. However, this is currently a link-only answer, which is discouraged here. If the tutorial ever goes offline, this answer won't have any value to future readers wondering how to solve this problem. To prevent that, it's best to edit your answer to summarize your main learnings from the tutorial, or outline the steps you took to follow it. That way the answer can be a useful guide even if the link rots.